# Where has logging to a file in Performance Monitor gone in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, logging, performance-monitor, perfmon

I am running perfmon in Windows 7 embedded and I can't find how you log the counter values to a file like you can in XP.

I thought it might be a limitation of Embedded 7 but I have the full version of Windows 7 installed in a VirtualBox and I can't find it there either.

MS help says:

> Open Log Files in Performance Monitor
>   Applies To: Windows 7, Windows Server
>   2008 R2, Windows Vista
>
> Membership in the local Users group,
>   or equivalent, is the minimum required
>   to complete this procedure.
>
> To open log files in Performance
>   Monitor In the Windows Performance
>   Monitor navigation pane, expand
>   Monitoring Tools and click Performance
>   Monitor.
>
> In the console pane toolbar, click the
>   Add Log Data button. The Performance
>   Monitor properties page will open at
>   the Source tab.

I can't find the Add Log Data button:

[image: Performance monitor screen shot]

Any clues?

Comment: They changed it drastically in W7...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744567(WS.10).aspx